# Я пытаюсь спавнить объект внутри канваса но он спавница неподходящего размера (слишком маленький ) Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity3d, android-canvas

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
    public GameObject canvas;

```
public GameObject bomd;
public float speedTime; //время спавна новой бомбочки
void Start ()
{
    StartCoroutine(SpawnCoroutine());

}



IEnumerator SpawnCoroutine()
{
    while (true) //(!Player.lose)
    {
        //Instantiate(bomd, new Vector2(Random.Range(-3.30f, 3.30f), -5.9f), Quaternion.identity);
        GameObject enemy = Instantiate(bomd, new Vector2(Random.Range(-126f, 126f), -277f), Quaternion.identity);
        enemy.transform.SetParent(canvas.transform, false);

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(speedTime); //время спавна 
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Если эти объекты не компоненты интерфейса, то не делайте этого. Может пострадать производительность из-за особености работы канвы.

Comment: Но мне нужно чтобы они спавнились одинаково под все екраны

Comment: Лучше опишите задачу, которую Вы решили добавлением (по всей видимости) игровых объектов в канву. Чего именно необходимо добиться?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

на держи.Создай файл в проекте и помести в него этот класс.Затем из любого другого скрипта/класса вызовешь метод UtilityScreen.ScaleMatchWidth. Функция подгоняет масштаб спрайта под ширину экрана, то есть меняет масштаб обьекта по оси х таким образом, чтобы он занимал заданную часть ширины экрана. Масштаб по осям y и z будет установлен таким же, как и по оси х . На вход ей даёшь игровой обьект,
который нужно подогнать, и число - необходимая ширина обьекта в процентах ширины экрана (при этом ширина экрана принимается за 100 %). В примере ниже твоя бомба будет иметь масштаб по оси х, равный десяти процентам от ширины экрана

```
GameObject bomb;
UtilityScreen.ScaleMatchWidth(bomb, 10.0f);





using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class UtilityScreen 
{

    public const float unit2meter = 2.0f;
    public const float meter2unit = 1.0f / unit2meter;

    static float s_screenWidth, s_screenHeight;
    public static Camera mainCamera;


    static UtilityScreen()
    {
        mainCamera = Camera.main;
        CalculateScreenBounds();
    }


    public static void CalculateScreenBounds()
    {
        Camera camera = mainCamera;

        Vector3 lowerLeft = camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3());
        Vector3 upperRight = camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(
            new Vector3(camera.pixelWidth, camera.pixelHeight, 0f));

        s_screenWidth = upperRight.x - lowerLeft.x;
        s_screenHeight = upperRight.y - lowerLeft.y;

    }

    public static float GetScreenWidth()
    {
        return s_screenWidth;
    }
    public static float GetScreenHeight()
    {
        return s_screenHeight;
    }
    public static Vector2 GetScreenSize()
    {
        return new Vector2(s_screenWidth, s_screenHeight);
    }


    public static void ScaleMatchWidth(GameObject sprite, float widthPercent)
    {
        SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer = sprite.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        if(spriteRenderer == null)
        {
            //Debug.Log(
            //    "Объект " + sprite.name + " не имеет компонента SpriteRenderer");

            return;
        }

        sprite.transform.localScale = Vector3.one;

        float currentSpriteWidth = spriteRenderer.bounds.size.x;
        float finalSpriteWidth = s_screenWidth * (widthPercent / 100.0f);

        float scale = finalSpriteWidth / currentSpriteWidth;
        sprite.transform.localScale = new Vector3(scale, scale, scale);
    }
}
```